# ubuntu installation using preseed

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, 15.10, preseed

I'm trying to do the unattended ubuntu installation using preseed.cfg. I am following the instruction as in http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Performing-an-automated-Ubuntu-install-using-preseeding

in the boot option I'm passing the parameter as

```
url=http://path/to/localhost/preseed.cfg locale=en_US
console-setup/ask_detect=false console-setup/layoutcode=us 
hostname=unassigned-hostname domain=unassigned-domain 
initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
```

but this returns an error `/install/initrd.gz is not found`.

Hence I changed the parameter to:

```
url=http://path/to/localhost/preseed.cfg initrd=/casper/initrd.gz
```

this prompts me an error *initramfs* error. Hence I updated the parameter to:

```
url=http://path/to/localhost/preseed.cfg boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.gz
```

This stops the auto installation at the language select. What is going wrong here?

[image: preseedinstall]

Answer (score 1):

The `debian-installer` is used for only for Server & Alternative CD. As you can see in [InstallCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization)

That reference is quiet old ~2010 and it is clear from screen-shot that it uses server image. AFAIK, Alternative image is not released any more for Ubuntu.

Live uses `ubiquity` installer, check in [UbiquityAutomation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation) for available options.

> ## Available preseeding keys
>
> Ubiquity uses a subset of the components that Ubuntu's version of
>   debian-installer uses and therefore asks the same questions for those
>   components. However, there are some additional questions provided.
>   These are as follows:
>
> - ubiquity/summary: preseed empty to avoid the summary page.
> - ubiquity/reboot: automatically reboot when the installer completes. Be sure to add 'noprompt' to the kernel command line to
>     also skip the "please remove the disc, close the tray (if any) and
>     press ENTER to continue" usplash prompt.
> - ubiquity/failure_command: specify a command to be run should the install fail.
> - ubiquity/success_command: similar to preseed/late_command. Specify a command to be run when the install completes successfully (runs
>     outside of /target, but /target is mounted when the command is
>     invoked).
>
> Furthermore, there are a few other components necessary for an
>   automated installation with ubiquity:
>
> - languagechooser/language-name: choose among the available languages, eg English
> - countrychooser/shortlist: choose a country, territory or area, eg US
> - localechooser/supported-locales: choose other locales to be supported, eg en_US.UTF-8
>
> Preseeding keys for the following installer components will not be
>   used in Ubiquity, usually because they do not fit with Ubiquity's mode
>   of operation:
>
> ```
> netcfg
> LVM and RAID partitioning
> base-installer
> pkgsel/tasksel
> finish-install
> ```
>
> You can use preseed/early_command with the live CD; it will be run by
>   "casper" (the component which sets up a live environment at boot time)
>   from the initramfs. Please note that, if you want to affect files in
>   the live environment, this means that you must prefix their filenames
>   with /root.

Comment: I have the preseed.cfg file in my local system and i'll be accessing it while installing it in virtual machine.

Comment: @SunShine, It is ok to store preseed.cfg on local system (sure you've setup an HTTP server already to serve VM system). But which CD image you are using? (from your screen-shot, it seems the standard Ubuntu live CD) . That CD used `ubiquity` installer, hence you should set `languagechooser/language-name`, `countrychooser/shortlist`...