# Is there such a thing as an Ubuntu 16.04 custom install, so I only install the apps that are necessary/dependant and my own choice?

Tags: system-installation

I've installed Ubuntu **a lot** over the years, and with my OCD I like things to be just right. I have it down to a fine art now, updated with the new features of 16.04:

**Pure Clean Default Install**, no network, no encryption - wipe disk and start from scratch, all my stuff is either in the cloud or on external media so it's all good.

**I install without network so** that I can remove unwanted apps before any unnecessary updates are detected, downloaded and installed.

On **first boot** after install I **do the same things each time**...

**Settings**:

- Security & Privacy > turn all off
- Time and Date > Clock > Weekday & Seconds
- Brightness and Lock > 30 minutes
- Text Entry > Keyboard Icon > Num Lock a couple of times until green is set
- Bluetooth > Off
- FOR SSD LAPTOP: Power > When lid is closed - do nothing

**Uninstall unused apps that are not needed but are pending update**:

With the new 16.04 (super fast) Ubuntu Software app, you can easily see ahead of time what updates the OS wants to install - use this tool to determine if you actually need those apps it's about to update. Up to now my default apps to remove are:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice* thunderbird unity-webapps-common gnome-calendar.
```

(*ps. I remove `libreoffice` as I use Google Drive, the choice is yours, same for client email Thunderbird vs webmail of any flavour*)

**Autoremove**:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove`
```

**Clean apt in readiness for first update and upgrade**:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

**Enable and configure firewall before connecting to the internet**:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

**Connect to Network > Update & Upgrade**:

- Plug in Ethernet or connect to wifi as normal (search for answers if you need help on this)
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

**Reboot**

**Install additional apps as required**:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser vlc gimp
```

(only install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` if you know you need all the included apps) - otherwise install the bits you need when you need them. For example Flash seems to be on it's way out, but if you need it install it:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

---

**So, to my question...** can this configuration, or something like it, be done ahead of time, so that, other than the dist-upgrade everything else is set as I'm aiming for?

Also, if I've missed any obvious, beneficial, efficiency or symmetry related configurations please let me know.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/759020/ubuntu-installation-using-preseed . Does the answer there answer your question?

Comment: OCD #1 - Settings: Time & Date > Clock > Weekday + Date & Month + Seconds

Comment: Thanks chaskes, I had a look at that link, but I don't think it gives me the control and customisation I'm looking for.

Comment: Most of this can be put into a script , but purging some of the programs might not be possible since unity desktop may or may not depend on them

Comment: Using preseeds should accomplish almost everything you wish. The other option is to do a custom iso.

Comment: Thanks Serg, can you please point me to a recommended resource to learn how to script quickly and efficiently - with a reasonably good technical background

Comment: Thanks Brian, can you share some more please... custom iso sounds like the kind of thing I was thinking of.

Comment: Start here : http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html  Basically , what i would do is install OS first, then boot , login, run the script, reboot if necessary

Comment: Thanks again Brian, preseeds I've never heard of, but will certainly investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

These two links should walk you through most of the steps necessary for creating a custom LiveCD. The LiveCD is created by first creating a custom iso with all of your desired settings preset. You can install/remove packages and modify the contents of the filesystem and persist those across installs. It's quite a bit of work but it accomplishes everything that you want.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that's a lot to chew on, so let me chew and I'll come back!

Comment: Sounds good, Just to note this can be combined with Preseeds that were mentioned above to create automated installers. This is something that we used at my University to build images for the computer science labs. It is also something I used in a research lab to do PXE booting with automated installers. It's a bunch of work but applications in the end are great.